# Delphi 2010 freeze on start-up

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, freeze

I've set up trial Delphi 2010 for the testing. After some days it is started and freeze. I just can see web-page with "how-to-buy" and at the right side last edited project. But Delphi's window do not react on any mouse events.

I've tried to reinstal and repair it.

So... What I have to do?
May be that project have bad files or some settings of IDE is incorrect?
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locate the .DSK file for any project it is trying to load, or the default.dsk file and delete it. Often this fixes Delphi startup failures. This file contains the desktop layout and list of open files.

Comment: Yeah... :) You were right! Tnx!
As I can see it was conflict of d2010 and d7.

Comment: Could you mark my answer as accepted then? Others will then know it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - this helped me too while using Delphi 10 Seattle!

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall and resointall?

Did you contact Embarcadero? At this point in any potential business transaction you are at your most powerful. You have not paid,  but it looks like you might; surely they would want to help you?

So, why ask us, rather than the company that wants to sell it to you?

Coupled with that - if you ask now you might get a rough idea of how helpful they could potentialy be if you ever do spring US $1k+

Comment: Tnx, for idea. :) I'll do it :) Оbviously I need to sleep if I don't think about this way.